# Setup internationalization i18n Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-admin, django-i18n

Following stackoverflow posts and a lot of tutorials to implement i18n internationalization in Django Admin I founded this steps:

***Command line Install** (in the right ENV)*

```
    Using PIP: pip install python-gettext (I tried this)

    Using Conda: conda install gettext
```

***settings.py***

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
                 ...
                 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
                 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', #right place
                 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
                 ...
    ]
    ...'context_processors': [
                 ...
                 'django.template.context_processors.i18n', # Indifferent place
                 ...
    ]
    ...
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'  # America/Sao_Paulo
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True        
    USE_TZ = True        
    ugettext = lambda s: s        
    LANGUAGES = (
            ( 'en-us', ugettext( 'English' )),
            ( 'pt-br', ugettext( 'Portuguese' )),
            ( 'es', ugettext( 'Spanish' )),
    )        
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' #default
    ...
    SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) )
    PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname( __name__ ) )
    LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join( SITE_ROOT, 'locale' ), ) # translation files will be created into 'locale' folder from root project folder
```

***urls.py***

```
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
        url( r'^favicon.ico$',
             RedirectView.as_view( url = staticfiles_storage.url( 'images/favicon.png' ), ),
             ),
        ...
]
<b>urlpatterns += i18n_patterns</b>(

        path( r'admin/',
              admin.site.urls
              ),
       ... 
)
urlpatterns += static(
        settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT ) \
             + static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

***models.py** (any)*

```
    from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
    ...
    class BusinessType(models.Model):
        businesstype_name = models.CharField(
             verbose_name = _( 'Business Name' ),
             help_text = _( 'Name, Field Type, Activity' ),
             max_length = 32, )
```

***Windows Users** (must have)*

Windows users need to download two packages from gnome project to built the i18n internationalization translation files to the right folder/directory - so download this to properly Windows 64/32 bits system [gettext-runtime-(last file version)_win64](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/dependencies/) or [win32](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/) *and download gettext-tools-(last file version) too*, Decompress all files to the same folder(gettext-tools inside BIN folder) and add Windows PATH variable to recognize these files.

***MAC Users** (must check this)*

I read a lot misspelled texts talking about the case/camel-Case into "languages" code are case sensitive, so take care if you use something like pt-*Br*:

```
    LANGUAGES = (
            ( 'en-us', ugettext( 'English' )),
            ( 'pt-br', ugettext( 'Portuguese' )),
            ( 'es', ugettext( 'Spanish' )),
    )
```

***Building templates files(.po)** (to write translations)*

```
    At terminal try this to built all specified languages in LANGUAGES and put "-v 3" to show how magic happening 

    python manage.py makemessages --all -v 3
```

***Nothing happens** (Someone have the same no-error like this)*

All this steps results into a 'locale' folder created, a 'python manage.py makemessages' supposedly worked and listing none, creating none, doing nothing, even not one error. **I'm really lost about this and after that, how I can retrieve the current selected language code to create alternative code to impossible i18n translations like:**

```
   PHONE REGEX rules, STATE list,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying a target language to create?

For example for spanish:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l es
```